# How would i turn every class returned into an array

Tags: javascript, html, class

I have the code below which returns each row in a website. Each row contains up to 8 rows of an address. I want to be able to turn each row of each address, for every address into an array.

I am a novice with JavaScript so any help will be greatly appreciated :)

```
<div class="classname" row="0" style="top:0px">
  <div class="row1" title> Address 1 </div>
  <div class="row2" title> Address 2 </div>
  <div class="row3" title> Address 3 </div>
  <div class="row4" title> Address 4 </div>
  <div class="row5" title> Address 5 </div>
  <div class="row6" title> Postcode </div>
  <div class="row7" title> Phone </div>
  <div class="row8" title> Email </div>
</div>
<div class="classname" row="1" style="top:0px">
  <div class="row1" title> Address 1 </div>
  <div class="row2" title> Address 2 </div>
  <div class="row3" title> Address 3 </div>
  <div class="row4" title> Address 4 </div>
  <div class="row5" title> Address 5 </div>
  <div class="row6" title> Postcode </div>
  <div class="row7" title> Phone </div>
  <div class="row8" title> Email </div>
</div>
```

```
for (var i = 0; i < Address.length; i++) {
  var AddAlert = Address[i].innerText;
  alert(AddAlert);
}
```

Comment: Check out [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Answer (score 2):

You should play around with the DOM API :

1. [document.querySelectorAll](https://devdocs.io/dom/document/queryselectorall)
2. [element.querySelectorAll](https://devdocs.io/dom/element/queryselectorall)

Or the [JQuery](https://jquery.com/) library.

However, here is a DOM solution explained...

```js
// Select all <div> having a 'row' attribute - i.e <div row=...>
// And since we call this on document, it matches for the whole html page
const rowNodes = document.querySelectorAll('div[row]');

const addresses = [];

for (let rowNode of rowNodes) {
    // Select all <div> having a class attribute with value of 'row1' or 'row2' or 'row3'...
    // And since we call this on rowNode, it matches ONLY for its descendants
    let addresseNodes = rowNode.querySelectorAll('div[class^="row"]');

    let rowAddresses = [];

    for (let addressNode of addresseNodes) {
        // You may want .innerText instead
        rowAddresses.push(addressNode.innerHTML);
    }

    addresses.push(rowAddresses);
}

// return addresses;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

> The Document method [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a static (not live) NodeList representing a list of the document's elements that match the specified group of selectors.

and [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

> The [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

Try the following way:

```js
var listP = document.querySelectorAll('.classname');
var res = Array.from(listP).map(function(el){
  return Array.from(el.querySelectorAll('[class^=row]')).map(i => i.innerText.trim());
});
console.log(res);
```

```html
<div class="classname" row="0" style="top:0px">
  <div class="row1" title> Address 1 </div>
  <div class="row2" title> Address 2 </div>
  <div class="row3" title> Address 3 </div>
  <div class="row4" title> Address 4 </div>
  <div class="row5" title> Address 5 </div>
  <div class="row6" title> Postcode </div>
  <div class="row7" title> Phone </div>
  <div class="row8" title> Email </div>
</div>
<div class="classname1" row="0" style="top:0px">
  <div class="row1" title> Address 1 </div>
  <div class="row2" title> Address 2 </div>
  <div class="row3" title> Address 3 </div>
  <div class="row4" title> Address 4 </div>
  <div class="row5" title> Address 5 </div>
  <div class="row6" title> Postcode </div>
  <div class="row7" title> Phone </div>
  <div class="row8" title> Email </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Apologies, i made an error when typing the HTML. The class names are identical however the row number changes. I have amended the question. Would this method still work?

Comment: @BradleySmith, of course the solution will work. `[class^=classNameStartsWith]` will match the class names starts with the provided string. Though `document.querySelectorAll('.classname')` is enough in that case. I have updated the answer please check:)